# How to Create More than one DropdownButton in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

User can Select Number between 1 to 10 in first page of the application, in second page i need to display 5 DropdownButton if the user selects 5 in the first screen.

Comment: Would you add your source code little bit?

Comment: why not? just passing the selected value from the first page to the second page and build a list of however many numbers of dropdown buttons should work

Comment: @Raycherr i can create list of widgets with the highest number but how to hide some widgets based on the number selection in the first page.